# Frirebase RT Database Delete Childs created With Auto Id

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm working on a simple grocery list app using Firebase RT Database(the data is presented in a UITableView). to keep everything simple when the user adds something to the list its added as Auto-GeneratedID: "Item added to list". My problem is in order to delete the item i need to get the child-id.

PS. I don't think i need to post any of my code. If anyone wants to see it let me know so i can post it.

Comment: Did you try posted solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by generating unique IDs and storing it with child information. Firebase allows to generate unique IDs.

**Generate Unique ID by Firebase:**

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("MyList")
let autogeneratedID = databaseRef.childByAutoId().key!
let dict_item: [String: Any] = ["id" : "\(autogeneratedID)", "name" : "pasta", "qty": 2]
databaseRef.child(autogeneratedID).setValue(dict_item)
```

By doing this, you will be storing **autogeneratedID** along with item details and it will be easy for you to get ID when needed for deletion.